# appcfg.py command keeps on returning usage : appcfg.py [options] <actions>

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine, cmd, appcfg

My cmd keeps on returning this for what ever appcfg.py command i give even appcfg.py -v I have python 2.7.9 I installed this version,i had same issue with 2.7.11. I have everything included in my path environment variable  My googleappengine is alo included into my path environment variable

[image]

So this hard coded command is working for me ....

```
python "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py" -A soy-key-124518 -V v1 update "C:\Users\Hamad\Desktop\ae-php\app"
```

What can the problem be?

Comment: FWIW, it may also worth checking TowMater7's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33137947/4495081

Comment: This happens a lot with Python scripts on Windows, and consequently gets asked frequently on Stack Overflow :) The above answer should help, and aside from editing the registry manually you can also try re-running the Python installer as an admin. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641225/appcfg-py-doesnt-work-the-parameters-in-command-line-are-always-neglected

Answer (score 1):

The `/app` path to the app dir seems incorrect:

- I'm unsure you can use the unix/linux `/` path delimiter in windows
- even if it can indeed be used, `/app` means either an absolute path (`C:\app`?) or the relative path to the `C:\Users\Hamad\app` dir (the current working dir appears to be `C:\Users\Hamad`) none of them matching the (absolute) path from the cmd that works: `C:\Users\Hamad\Desktop\ae-php\app`.

Try using the full path to the app dir (the same as in the cmd that works) or the proper relative path depending on the actual dir in which you execute that cmd.

Comment: I did use absolute path to the dir. It still wont work.

Comment: I had this same problem. Ever since to gcloud update the command has changed but the documentation has not. I used to be able to run the command: "appcfg.py download_app..." now I have to run "python appcfg.py download_app..." I realize you are using PHP but you might have to specify the runtime environment in front of the appcfg file.

Comment: @Doug please note that `python` in "python appcfg.py ..." is **not** the runtime environment, it's just the local python executable needed to run the `appcfg.py` (python) script, see my answer to the duplicate question (which may also explain why you can't execute `appcfg.py` directly). I mean for the PHP runtime it'll still have to be `python`.